# How to modify my existing query to create a new column in my table and feed it with this specific data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query which extract all duplicate records based on the "Email" column of my Table (t1):

```
use MyDatabase

;WITH [CTE1] AS (
    select
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY [Email] ORDER BY [Email])
        , *    
    from [t1]    
)    
SELECT *
FROM [CTE1]        
WHERE [RowNum] > 1
```

The query runs fine and gives the following output (extract):

```
 RowNum      ID       Name    Email
   2         100      John    john@xyz.com
   2         255      Allan   ag@mail64.com
   2         211      Allan   ag@mail64.com
   2         126      Peter   ps@noemail.com
   2         110      Peter   ps@noemail.com
   3         144      Peter   ps@noemail.com
   4         220      Peter   ps@noemail.com
   ...
```

How can I modify my query to get the following output (note: Column "Tag" should be created on the table t1:

```
 RowNum      ID       Name    Email             Tag
   2         100      John    john@xyz.com      dup
   2         255      Allan   ag@mail64.com     dup
   2         211      Allan   ag@mail64.com     dup
   2         126      Peter   ps@noemail.com    dup
   2         110      Peter   ps@noemail.com    dup
   3         144      Peter   ps@noemail.com    dup 
   4         220      Peter   ps@noemail.com    dup
   ...
```

Note: Records with RowNum = 1 should have a blank in the "Tag" column.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: But your "desired output" does not include the first row from among a set of duplicates nor does it even show an example where "tag" is blank. And the phrase "Column "Tag" should be created on the table t1" is confusing. Are you suggesting you want to create a new column in your table or just add it to the query resultset? or both?

Comment: Create the new column "Tag" and fill it with "dup" or "blanks"...therefore, both. I did not show an example of a record where "tag" column is blank as I thought it was obvious as my concern was to fill the "Tag" column  with "dup", otherwise leave a blank.

Comment: So apparently you don't want "the following output" - you want to both add a column to your existing table and then to update that column by setting it to 'dup' for those certain rows. Stu has guessed well it seems - did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you won't want to filter out rows with `Rownum=1`, simply use a `case` expression.

```
SELECT *, case when rownum=1 then '' else 'dup' end as Tag
FROM [CTE1]
```

If you have the column `Tag` on your table `t1` you can include it in the `select` and run an update on the CTE

```
update CTE1 set
  Tag=case when rownum=1 then '' else 'dup' end
```

You should probably change your ordering criteria to be based on `Id` to consistently keep the highest/lowest id of each group, currently you are assigning duplicates based on the alphabetical sorting of the email.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
USE MyDatabase;

DECLARE @Table  TABLE (RowNum int , ID int, Name varchar(50), EMail varchar(100), Tag varchar(3));

INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT
            RowNum  =   ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY T1.[Email] ORDER BY T1.[Email])
        ,   ID      =   T1.ID
        ,   Name    =   T1.Name 
        ,   EMail   =   T1.[EMail]
        ,   Tag     =   ''
    FROM    T1  
;
UPDATE T1
    SET Tag = CASE RowNum WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE 'dup' END
;

SELECT *
FROM @Table
```